# How to allow simultaneous reads from a synchronized structure?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

Suppose I have a simple cache implementation like this:

```
class Cache<Item> {
    private InternalStorage internalStorage;

    public synchronized Collection<Item> find(String query) {
        // find Items from internalStorage
    }

    public synchronized void add(Collection<Item> items) {
        // Add items to internalStorage
    }
}
```

I need to prevent:

1. Simultaneous writes to `internalStorage`. i.e. No simultaneous calls to `add`.
2. Reads occurring at the same time as a write. i.e. Can't call `find` and `add` at the same time.

The implementation above satisfies these safety requirements, however, there is no harm in simultaneous calls to `find` because it does not change the data. How can I allow that, while still keep the structure thread-safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this is fairly easy to do if you would use a `ReentrantReadWriteLock` instead of `synchronized` here.

Comment: @PeterHall `ReadWriteLock` was added for this particular reason... the documentation is very clear in this regard too btw. So, yeah, it should work

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [Eugene's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52149061/493729). This is how to apply a `ReentrantReadWriteLock` to achieve what I needed:

```
class Cache<Item> {
    final ReentrantReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    private Map<String, Item> internalStorage;

    public Collection<Item> find(String query) {
        rwl.readLock().lock();
        try {
            // find Items from internalStorage
            // ...
            return result;
        } finally {
            rwl.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public void add(Collection<Item> items) {
        rwl.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            // Add items to internalStorage
            // ...
        } finally {
            rwl.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```